# SocketException when using NpgsqlConnection

Tags: c#, npgsql, system.net.sockets

Getting a very generic error and cannot seem to find enough information apart from saying it's an error which shouldn't happen.

Code below produces the following error:

```
NpgsqlConnection Conn = new NpgsqlConnection("Host=192.168.50.240;Port=5432;Username=postgres;Password=*******;Database=postgres;");
Conn.Open();
```

> System.Net.Sockets.SocketException (10107): Unknown error (0x277b)
> at Interop.Winsock.g__Initialize|55_0()
> at System.Net.Sockets.SocketPal.CreateSocket(AddressFamily addressFamily, SocketType socketType, ProtocolType protocolType, SafeSocketHandle& socket)
> at System.Net.Sockets.Socket..ctor(AddressFamily addressFamily, SocketType socketType, ProtocolType protocolType)
> at Npgsql.Internal.NpgsqlConnector.Connect(NpgsqlTimeout timeout)
> at Npgsql.Internal.NpgsqlConnector.RawOpen(SslMode sslMode, NpgsqlTimeout timeout, Boolean async, CancellationToken cancellationToken, Boolean isFirstAttempt)
> at Npgsql.Internal.NpgsqlConnector.g__OpenCore|215_1(NpgsqlConnector conn, SslMode sslMode, NpgsqlTimeout timeout, Boolean async, CancellationToken cancellationToken, Boolean isFirstAttempt)
> at Npgsql.Internal.NpgsqlConnector.Open(NpgsqlTimeout timeout, Boolean async, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
> at Npgsql.PoolingDataSource.OpenNewConnector(NpgsqlConnection conn, NpgsqlTimeout timeout, Boolean async, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
> at Npgsql.PoolingDataSource.g__RentAsync|28_0(NpgsqlConnection conn, NpgsqlTimeout timeout, Boolean async, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
> at Npgsql.NpgsqlConnection.g__OpenAsync|45_0(Boolean async, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
> at Npgsql.NpgsqlConnection.Open()

The server is located in a docker container on another machine.
I can access the server from the same Windows 10 machine with the error using DBeaver without issue.

I have tried:

- SSL Mode=Disable
- Pooling=False

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: If you haven't already, I suggest first to check out the ticket here:  https://github.com/npgsql/efcore.pg/issues/166  .  Note, they suggest that if you cannot telnet to the IP+Port, that it is a networking issue and not a Npgsql issue.  (because you can connect with another client, this might be OK, but best to check out some basics first just to be sure).

Comment: No its not a networking issue as can connect fine.  After doing some further testing it seems to be a conflict issue with another namespace.  Honestly, it seems to deeply ingrained to fix efficiently.  Will try another approach.